# How does (SSIS) Integrated Services send email?

Tags: python, sql-server, ssis, smtp, exchange-server

I'm trying to send emails using python smtp library but get the following an error message when trying to send to external email addresses (internal email works):
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'test@gmail.com': (550, ' Relaying denied')}

This is because we have rules setup on our exchange that prevent relaying from client machines.

What I don't understand is how come I can send emails over SMTP with an SSIS package without getting the relay error.

Is there a setting I need to enable in my python to bypass this or is SSIS sending the email to SQL Server to send on its behalf.

Comment: How do you have it set up in SSIS? Are you using the SMTP Send Mail Task or do you have an Execute SQL Task which calls `sp_send_dbmail` which then sends the email message? When you execute your python script, is it on the same machine that is running SSIS packages?

Comment: The SSIS package is using the SMTP Send Mail Task. I'm running both on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are getting this due to authentication. SSIS is probably passing your windows credentials through but when you are trying to send with python your credentials are being denied.
Not 100% sure that is your issue. But a thought.

Comment: The python examples I've seen never include sending login information. When I try to smtplib.login(username, password) I get "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server."